# Finding & Replacing a Word within a Div Using Good Ole JavaScript

Tags: javascript, replace

I know this is quite easy to do in jQuery, but I am trying to do it in JavaScript.

I have this:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {

        function replaceName() {
        var oldText= "Mobile";
        var newText = "Stackoverflow";
        var oldString= document.getElementById('replace').innerHTML;
        var newString = oldString.replace(/oldText/g, newText);
        document.getElementById('replace').innerHTML = newString;
        }

        replaceName();

}, false);
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong? Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
var newString = oldString.replace(/oldText/g, newText);
```

It's actually searching for `oldText` and not `"Mobile"`

As kb said, you can solve this by:

```
var newString = oldString.replace(new RegExp(oldText, "g"), newText);
```

Comment: It should be possible to use the full syntax instead of short form when defining the regular expression, `var reg = new RegExp(oldText, "g");` and then use `oldString.replace(reg, newText);` for example.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend `eval` in any situation where it isn't absolutely necessary. Even if you think it *is* absolutely necessary, you're probably wrong.

Answer (score 7):

Currently, you are doing it the *error prone* way.

Error prone because you will lose event handlers as well as replacing things you may not want to replace. What if the search term was `'a'`? Would you want all `a` elements turning into whatever the replace string is?

Also, you are needlessly serialising the HTML from the DOM of which needs to be reparsed when you set it again.

The correct way to do this is to iterate over the text nodes only.

```
var replaceText = function replaceText(element, search, replace) {
    var nodes = element.childNodes;

    for (var i = 0, length = nodes.length; i < length; i++) {

        var node = nodes[i];

        if (node.childNodes.length) {
            replaceText(node, search, replace);
            continue;
        }

        if (node.nodeType != 3) {
            continue;
        }

        node.data = node.data.replace(new RegExp(search, 'g'), replace);
    }

}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/erMJt/).

Comment: Care to add a benchmark? I'm actually willing to bet (figuratively) that this method with innerHTML isn't as bad as you might expect (varies per browser/version). For one because you have only 2 calls to the DOM. Iterating over textNodes can be cumbersome.

Comment: @Frits Even if it is slower than working with `innerHTML`, you get the benefit of not mangling HTML or losing event handlers bound with properties.

Comment: Also has the benefit of avoiding matching characters within the markup and the differences between what browsers think is the innerHTML property. Agree though that performance is likely slower (but that does not make up for all the cons with innerHTML).

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of providing an answer that doesn't use `eval` (repeat after me: don't use `eval`!), try this line:

```
var newString = oldString.replace(new RegExp(oldText, "g"), newText);
```

Where previously you had `/pattern/flags`, now you have `new RegExp(pattern, flags)`

Answer (score 0):

Just set

```
var oldText = /Mobile/g
```

Comment: That doesn't work :P - It's no longer a regex but a normal string. This is why I initially used the eval.

Comment: @Frits, thanks, forgot to leave the quotes off, since it's a regexp object.  The new RegExp() way is better though.

Comment: Yes well, the whole idea is of course that `oldText` varies, it's not always `Mobile`.

Comment: @Frits, yep, I'd make it dynamic in any of my apps.